# Boolean NOT updating when in sculpt mode

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier, sculpt-mode

I have an active difference boolean modifier on an object.

When I go into the sculpt mode and sculpt on the cutter object, it doesn't update the boolean unless I switch back to object mode and then switch back to sculpt mode again to view the change and sculpt again.

I would like the boolean to update in real time as and when I'm sculpting on the cutter object.

Is there any way I could achieve that result?